# maraDNS NON-AUTH timeout

Tags: bind, nameserver, domain-name-system

I've set up maraDNS to provide my own DNS records. I've pointed the domain nameservers at my registrar to ns1.domain.co.uk and ns2.domain.co.uk (using domain in place of actual domain name).

I cannot resolve the hostname - it has been 2 days. Using mxtoolbox.com returns this:

```
MXTB-PWS3v2 7098ms
  0  nsc.nic.uk  156.154.102.3  NON-AUTH  46 ms  Received 2 Referrals , rcode=NO_ERROR    NS ns2.domain.co.uk,NS ns1.domain.co.uk,  

  1  ns2.domain.co.uk  1.1.1.1  NON-AUTH  46 ms  Timeout after 3 sec, rcode=NO_ERROR      

  1  ns1.domain.co.uk  2.2.2.2  NON-AUTH  46 ms  Timeout after 3 sec, rcode=NO_ERROR
```

The nameservers and IP it lists are correct.

MaraDNS shows no error messages even with verbose set.
After showing MaraDNS start up correctly syslog states:

```
/usr/sbin/maradns:  Log: Awaiting data on port 53
```

My setting for MaraDNS are these:

mararc:

```
csv2 = {}
csv2["domain.co.uk."] = "db.domain.co.uk"
csv2["domain.com."] = "db.domain.com"

ipv4_bind_addresses = "1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2"
chroot_dir = "/etc/maradns"
hide_disclaimer = "YES"
verbose_level = 3
```

db.domain.co.uk:

```
domain.co.uk. SOA domain.co.uk. hostmaster@domain.co.uk. /serial 7200 3600 604800 1800
domain.co.uk. NS ns1.domain.co.uk.
domain.co.uk. MX 10 mail.domain.co.uk.
domain.co.uk. FQDN4 3.3.3.3
ns1.domain.co.uk. A 1.1.1.1
ns2.domain.co.uk. A 2.2.2.2
mail.domain.co.uk. A 4.4.4.4
billing.domain.co.uk. A 5.5.5.5
forum.domain.co.uk. A 6.6.6.6
cp.domain.co.uk. A 7.7.7.7
www.domain.co.uk. CNAME domain.co.uk.
```

If anyone has any ideas I would greatly appreciate any help. I chose maraDNS over BIND as I was led to believe it was simpler.

Thank you

Comment: What does a `netstat -an | grep 53` say ?

Comment: Stupidly set iptables to allow tcp 53 not udp 53!

Comment: It happens to the best of us.. (a group I don't really qualify to be in) :)